# Defining ABI version Android Studio when using SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

two weeks ago I uploaded a new version of my Android app to the Developer Console to run an Alpha Test. However I was not able to download this test version on my test device, since the Play Store offered no such update to my test user.

After I was not able to solve this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37316146) I contacted the Google Developer Support directly.

I now received the following reply:

> I’ve looked into your issue and found that your app's Version 15 is not compatible with the Nexus 5 due to a conflict in your app’s manifest with the following native platforms: armeabi, armeabi-v7a.
>
> For more information about platforms, visit our developer site at https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html

This is quite confusing. As far as I understand the information on the linked page, the ABI setting is only available/relevant when working with the `NDK`. However I am working with the latest `SDK` version in `Android Studio 2.1`

**Is it even possible to set/define the ABI version when working with the SDK?**

The App Manifest does not include any settings related the the ABI version.

When I copy the APK manually to my device (Nexus 5 running Android 4.4.4) and install it, it runs without any problem. So, is the APK really not compatible with my device?

**EDIT:**

Inspired by the the comment by **user1056837** I found [this page](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental), that describes how to add an `NDK` block to the `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    ...

    ndk {
        // All configurations that can be changed in android.ndk.
        ...
    }

    productFlavors {
        create("arm") {
            ndk {
                // You can customize the NDK configurations for each
                // productFlavors and buildTypes.
                abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
            }
        }

        create("fat") {
            // If ndk.abiFilters is not configured, the application
            // compile and package all suppported ABI.
        }
    }
}
```

Currently my `build.gradle` file does **NOT** include any NDK configuration. I am not sure, how I could solve the problem with the Play Store by adding such config.

As far as I understand the information on the linked page, a **fat binary** will be created of no `abiFilters` are configured. Is that correct?

Then one of the following should be correct:

1. My project **does** contain some native code without my knowledge. In this case a fat binary is created since my `build.gradle` file does **NOT** include any NDK configuration.
2. My project **does not** contain any hidden native code. In this case the NDK config would not have any effect at all.

Did I miss something here? No matter which case is correct, in both scenarios I do not know what config would solve the problem...

Comment: App manifest does not provide information of what ABI is supported, it only can be seen by checking what type of native libraries are present in apk file (on windows with cygwin i do this one-liner to check: `aapt l example.apk | grep .so`)

Comment: I am working on OS X and I have not been able to use `appt` command. I will try to figure this out. But as said in the question I am not sure if the ABI version can really be the source of the problem. All information I found is only relevant when using with the `NDK` but I am using the `Java SDK`. Java creates platform independent byte code. Why should the binary version be relevant in this case?

Comment: maybe some 3rd party libraries are adding architecture specific binaries to your app. if you can't find aapt, open your APK as a zip file and look inside the *lib* folder if there are any subfolders with .so files inside them.

Comment: @ph0b Thanks for the hint. However the `lib` folder inside the `APK` **does not** include any `.so` files. There is only one file in this folder which is the `commons-io-2.4.jar` which is the `org.apache.commons.io` lib. So, no luck with the `.so` files. Any other idea how to check if there are any NDK problems in my APK? I am still not convinced that Google is right with this...

Comment: Just add to your `build.gradle` file ndk-block into android->defaultConfig section and set `abiFilters` manually.

Comment: Could you explain this in more detail? I have updated the question taking the new information into account I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is to late, but nevertheless:
I had the same problem. It was in third-party libraries. When my application started to build, the library bitcoinj created a native script in the `/lib/x86_64/darwin/libscrypt.dylib folder`. I just excluded this folder in the build.gradle file.

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'lib/x86_64/darwin/libscrypt.dylib'
}
```

After that all started work fine. My app support 5900 devices now.